# How to link progress-streamer with node-mailer for more than one attachments?

Tags: node.js, progress-bar, email-attachments, nodemailer

My code for sending mailing with multiple files as an attachment using [node mailer](https://nodemailer.com) js was working before adding progress-bar and for progress-bar I use [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream). It shows progress bar but the receiver only receives only one corrupted file.

**My code is here**

```
function mail() {
  getSelected(); // this function store addresses of all the files in checked array
  att = [];
  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: document.getElementById("from").value,
      pass: document.getElementById("ps").value
    }
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) { //measuring total size of files 
    attSize += fs.statSync(checked[i])["size"];
  }

  var progress = require('progress-stream');
  var str = progress({
    length: attSize,
    time: 100 /* ms */
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) { //adding all src/path of selected files in att

    attSize += fs.statSync(path)["size"];
    att.push({
      filename: filename,
      content: fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(str)
    });


  }


  str.on('progress', function(progress) {
    if (progress.length == 100) {
      toast("Sending Email!", 500);
    } else {
      showToast('Uploading Attachment :' + progress.length + ' %');
    }


  });


  var mailOptions = {
    from: document.getElementById("from"),
    to: document.getElementById("to").value,
    subject: 'Custom Subject',
    text: 'This is simple text ... That was easy!',
    attachments: att
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      toast(error, 2000);
    } else {
      toast('Email sent: ' + info.response, 2000);
    }
  });
}
```

I think the problem is here

```js
content: fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(str)
```

So If I use `.pipe(str)` in more than one files progress bar is working but attachment images are corrupted and instead of multiple files receiver only receives one file